# How to make content disappear when you scroll passed it?

Tags: javascript

I am making a scroll effect in JavaScript. I can make it appear when you scroll down, but how to make it disappear when you scroll past it?

this is what I got so far.

```
window.onload = function(){
  const EFFECT = document.querySelector("#about_page");

  window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollEffect);

  function scrollEffect(){
    if(window.scrollY >= 550) {
      EFFECT.style.opacity = '1';
      EFFECT.style.transform = 'scale(1)';
      EFFECT.style.transition = '500ms ease-in-out';
    }

    else if(window.scrollY <= 500) {
      EFFECT.style.opacity = '0';
      EFFECT.style.transform = 'scale(0)';
      EFFECT.style.transition = '500ms ease-in-out';
    }

    else {
      EFFECT.style.opacity = '0';
      EFFECT.style.transform = 'scale(0)';
    }
  }
  scrollEffect();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an upper-bound to your first `if` statement:

```
if(window.scrollY >= 550 && window.scrollY < 750) {
```

Just replace `750` with whatever value you want to trigger the fade-out.